# Older Road Bike Tire Size

Tags: tire

I recently bought an older Takara road bike.  The sidewalls look like they are rotting so I want to replace them but cannot read the size.  I have tried a 700x250 tire but it does not fit.  Any ideas what size would fit and where is a good place to buy them?[image]

Comment: I assume you mean 700x25. Did the tire not fit on the rim, or did it not fit in the bike?

Comment: Great photo, by the way.

Comment: The tire did not fit the rim

Comment: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The size is 32-630, also known as 27" x 1 1/4. It is slightly larger than the common 28" or 700C tire.

Comment: Example: https://www.thebikesmiths.com/products/kenda-k35?variant=222033117202&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Google%20Shopping&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI45bn0LDW5QIVENVkCh3XXAf7EAQYASABEgIOR_D_BwE

Comment: You can get a somewhat wider or narrower tire, but you need the same diameter.

Comment: 32-630 tyres are still available. Google!

Comment: I ended up ordering replacement tires from thebikesmiths.com.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a great guide to tyre sizes](https://www.cyclinguk.org/cyclists-library/components/wheels-tyres/tyre-sizes) including a handy chart.  From Cycling UK.  From the chart it looks like you have two potential options for the rims you have.  Those being 25mm width or the 32mm width of the originals you want to replace.

I believe it may be possible to replace the wheels you have on the bike with 700c ones.  Of course, you then have to find brakes with enough 'reach' to account for the slightly smaller diameter of the rims.  You then have a much wider range of tyre options available...